# React Router caught the following error during render TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendWithStream')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-pdf

In my project, there is a component called Pdfviewer that show some pdf from url. I am using react-pdf https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf to show the pdf like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styles from './Previewer.module.css';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;
import 'react-pdf/dist/Page/TextLayer.css';
import 'react-pdf/dist/Page/AnnotationLayer.css';

export type ViewerProps = {
    pdfUrl: string | undefined;
};

const Previewer: React.FC<ViewerProps> = (props: ViewerProps) => {

    const [pdfScale, setPdfScale] = useState<number>(1);
    const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState<number>();
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState<number>(1);

    const options = {
        cMapUrl: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/cmaps/',
    };

    if (!props.pdfUrl) {
        return (<div>Loading</div>);
    }

    const handleDownloadPdf = async (pdfUrl: any) => {
        if (!pdfUrl) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            const response = await fetch(pdfUrl);
            const blob = await response.blob();
            const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = downloadUrl;
            link.setAttribute('download', 'main.pdf');
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error downloading PDF:', error);
        }
    }

    const handleZoomIn = async () => {
        setPdfScale(pdfScale + 0.1);
    }

    const handleZoomOut = async () => {
        setPdfScale(pdfScale - 0.1);
    }

    const onDocumentLoadSuccess = (pdf: any) => {
        const { doc, numPages } = pdf;
        setNumPages(numPages);
    }

    const handlePageChange = (page: any) => {
        //setCurrentPage(page);
    };

    const handlePageRenderSuccess = (page: any) => {
        const pageIndex = page._pageIndex + 1;
    };

    const renderPages = (totalPageNum: number | undefined) => {
        if (!totalPageNum || totalPageNum < 1) return;
        const tagList: JSX.Element[] = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= totalPageNum; i++) {
            tagList.push(
                <Page key={i}
                    className={styles.pdfPage}
                    scale={pdfScale}
                    onLoad={handlePageChange}
                    onRenderSuccess={handlePageRenderSuccess}
                    pageNumber={i} >

                </Page>
            );
        }
        return tagList;
    }

    return (
        <div id="preview" className={styles.preview}>
            <div className={styles.previewHader}>
                <div className={styles.leftAction}>
                    <button className={styles.previewButton}>
                        <i className="fa-regular fa-file-pdf"></i> Preview
                    </button>
                    <button className={styles.previewButton}>
                        <i className="fa-regular fa-file-lines"></i> Log
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.rightAction}>
                    <button className={styles.previewIconButton} onClick={() => { handleDownloadPdf(props.pdfUrl) }}>
                        <i className="fa-solid fa-download"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button className={styles.previewIconButton} id="zoominbutton" onClick={() => { handleZoomIn() }}>
                        <i className="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button className={styles.previewIconButton} id="zoomoutbutton" onClick={() => { handleZoomOut() }}>
                        <i className="fa fa-search-minus"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.previewBody}>
                <Document options={options} file={props.pdfUrl} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
                    {renderPages(numPages)}
                </Document>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.previewFooter}>
                <p>
                    Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Previewer;
```

everything works fine, but sometimes shows error when render the pdf textlayer:

```
Warning: getTextContent - ignoring errors during "GetTextContent: page 0" task: "Error: Worker task was terminated".
unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.6.172/build/pdf.worker.min.js:22 Warning: getTextContent - ignoring errors during "GetTextContent: page 1" task: "Error: Worker task was terminated".
unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.6.172/build/pdf.worker.min.js:22 Warning: getTextContent - ignoring errors during "GetTextContent: page 0" task: "Error: Worker task was terminated".
unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.6.172/build/pdf.worker.min.js:22 Warning: getTextContent - ignoring errors during "GetTextContent: page 1" task: "Error: Worker task was terminated".
unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.6.172/build/pdf.worker.min.js:22 Warning: getOperatorList - ignoring errors during "GetOperatorList: page 0" task: "Error: Worker task was terminated".
unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.6.172/build/pdf.worker.min.js:22 Warning: getOperatorList - ignoring errors during "GetOperatorList: page 1" task: "Error: Worker task was terminated".
2unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.6.172/build/pdf.worker.min.js:22 Warning: getTextContent - ignoring errors during "GetTextContent: page 2" task: "Error: Worker task was terminated".
unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@3.6.172/build/pdf.worker.min.js:22 Warning: getOperatorList - ignoring errors during "GetOperatorList: page 2" task: "Error: Worker task was terminated".
react-dom.development.js:22839 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendWithStream')
    at PDFPageProxy.streamTextContent (api.js:1609:43)
    at renderTextLayer (TextLayer.js:123:40)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:26)
    at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23268:17)
    at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24688:9)
    at commitLayoutEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24674:7)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:24612:3)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26823:5)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26682:5)
    at finishConcurrentRender (react-dom.development.js:25981:9)
streamTextContent @ api.js:1609
renderTextLayer @ TextLayer.js:123
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23268
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25981
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 14 more frames
Show less
console.js:213 Error handled by React Router default ErrorBoundary: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendWithStream')
    at PDFPageProxy.streamTextContent (api.js:1609:43)
    at renderTextLayer (TextLayer.js:123:40)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:26)
    at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23268:17)
    at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24688:9)
    at commitLayoutEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24674:7)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:24612:3)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26823:5)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26682:5)
    at finishConcurrentRender (react-dom.development.js:25981:9) 
    at DefaultErrorComponent (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3255:15)
    at RenderErrorBoundary (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3287:5)
    at DataRoutes (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3648:5)
    at Router (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3727:15)
    at RouterProvider (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3597:5)
    at Provider (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-HPHZGAQ2.js?v=db6378d7:1315:3)
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
DefaultErrorComponent @ hooks.tsx:513
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26085
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26959
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25981
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 18 more frames
Show less
console.js:213 Error handled by React Router default ErrorBoundary: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendWithStream')
    at PDFPageProxy.streamTextContent (api.js:1609:43)
    at renderTextLayer (TextLayer.js:123:40)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:26)
    at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23268:17)
    at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24688:9)
    at commitLayoutEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24674:7)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:24612:3)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26823:5)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26682:5)
    at finishConcurrentRender (react-dom.development.js:25981:9)     at DefaultErrorComponent (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3255:15)    at RenderErrorBoundary (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3287:5)    at DataRoutes (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3648:5)    at Router (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3727:15)    at RouterProvider (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3597:5)    at Provider (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-HPHZGAQ2.js?v=db6378d7:1315:3)
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
overrideMethod @ console.js:267
DefaultErrorComponent @ hooks.tsx:513
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20145
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26085
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26959
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25981
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 19 more frames
Show less
console.js:213 The above error occurred in the <TextLayer> component:

    at TextLayer (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-pdf.js?v=db6378d7:18100:23)
    at div
    at Page2 (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-pdf.js?v=db6378d7:18380:27)
    at div
    at Document2 (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-pdf.js?v=db6378d7:17168:9)
    at div
    at div
    at Previewer (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/src/component/common/previewer/Previewer.tsx?t=1692757163534:27:35)
    at div
    at div
    at App (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/src/page/main/App.tsx?t=1692759839580:39:18)
    at RenderedRoute (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3327:5)
    at RenderErrorBoundary (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3287:5)
    at DataRoutes (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3648:5)
    at Router (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3727:15)
    at RouterProvider (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3597:5)
    at Provider (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-HPHZGAQ2.js?v=db6378d7:1315:3)

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, RenderErrorBoundary.
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
callback @ react-dom.development.js:18755
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23364
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26959
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25981
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 20 more frames
Show less
console.js:213 React Router caught the following error during render TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sendWithStream')
    at PDFPageProxy.streamTextContent (api.js:1609:43)
    at renderTextLayer (TextLayer.js:123:40)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:26)
    at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23268:17)
    at commitLayoutMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24688:9)
    at commitLayoutEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24674:7)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:24612:3)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26823:5)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26682:5)
    at finishConcurrentRender (react-dom.development.js:25981:9) {componentStack: '\n    at TextLayer (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node…s/.vite/deps/chunk-HPHZGAQ2.js?v=db6378d7:1315:3)'} 
    at RenderErrorBoundary (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3287:5)
    at DataRoutes (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3648:5)
    at Router (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3727:15)
    at RouterProvider (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-BCO3PSJ7.js?v=db6378d7:3597:5)
    at Provider (http://dev-tex.poemhub.top/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-HPHZGAQ2.js?v=db6378d7:1315:3)
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
componentDidCatch @ hooks.tsx:608
callback @ react-dom.development.js:18768
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23364
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26959
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25981
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 20 more frames
Show less
2console.js:213 Warning: AbortException: TextLayer task cancelled.
```

it seems when the component tried to render the document text layer, the pdf worker has already terminated. what should I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: The error messages you're seeing are related to the PDF.js worker being terminated before it completes its tasks. This can happen for various reasons, such as:

The worker taking too long and being terminated by the browser.
The component being unmounted before the worker finishes its tasks.
Conflicts with other libraries or components.
Issues with the specific version of the react-pdf library or pdfjs-dist you're using.

Comment: it hard to found the reason, I will try to find out.